# SQL Server - Sorting column based on string and number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have a table with one column which contains combination of string and number like as shown below. I need to sort the name column in descending or ascending but the problem is when I use ORDER BY it is not sorting as expected

[image]

My query is like as shown below

```
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY `name` ASC
```

My expected result is like as shown blow

```
employee1
employee2
employee3
employee6
employee6
employee10
employee11
employee12
employee17
employee82
employee100
employee111
employee129
employee299
```

Can anyone please help me on this

Comment: Is the alphabetic part or the text fixed throughout the resultset, or can it be `employee1` in one row and `manager3` in another? if the later, how would you want to sort it? based on numbers only? based on numbers then text? based on text than numbers? Also, are the numbers always at the end or can it be `1employee` and `employee3`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below by only extracting the number part from the field

```
SELECT * FROM test 
ORDER BY cast(replace(`name`,'employee','') as int) ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...the looks fine...but the problem is that there is no grantee what exactly the string will be. Just for an example I have used **employee**

Answer (score 0):

Since the number always in the end, you can do as

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT 'employee1' Name
union all select 'employee2'
union all select 'employee3'
union all select 'employee6'
union all select 'employee6'
union all select 'employee10'
union all select 'employee11'
union all select 'employee12'
union all select 'employee17'
union all select 'employee82'
union all select 'employee100'
union all select 'employee111'
union all select 'employee129'
union all select 'employee299'
)
SELECT Name
FROM CTE
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(Name, PATINDEX('%[^a-z, '' '']%', Name), LEN(Name)) AS INT)
--OR PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Name)
```

Or

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT 'The First Employee 1' Name
union all select 'The Second One 2'
union all select 'Employee Number 4'
union all select 'Employee Number 3'
)
SELECT Name
FROM CTE
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(Name, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Name), LEN(Name)) AS INT)
```

Here is a **[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a707e5b5428431898426b387ad4cbea5)** where you can change the strings and see the results.

Finnaly, I would note to the real problem, which is *a table with just one column and no PK*.

Comment: lets say **employee2-555**

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below:

```
-- ASSUMES NUMBERS ARE IN THE LAST CHARACTER
-- WONT WORK IF NUMBER IS THERE IN THE MIDDLE

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #data

select 
 Name        = REPLACE(name,' ','') 
,NameWithNum = REPLACE(name,' ','') + cast(object_id as varchar(100))
INTO #data
from sys.tables

SELECT 
 NameWithNum
,NameRemovedNumbers= SUBSTRING(NameWithNum, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', NameWithNum), LEN(NameWithNum))
from #data
ORDER BY Name,SUBSTRING(NameWithNum, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', NameWithNum), LEN(NameWithNum))
```

Comment: what will be the case if the string contains special characters

Comment: lets say employee2-555

Answer (score 0):

The "base" part of the name is the same.  So, you can order by the length and then the name:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM test t
ORDER BY LEN(name), name;
```